# VS Code warning: Skipping standard library file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8, isort

I only started work with vscode and added in my project flake8, isort and get this erros, how can I fix it?

[image: Skipping standart library file]

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).

Comment: Judging by the path, you seem to be modifying the source code? Can [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-isort/issues/172) help?

Comment: I didn't modify the source code, I reinstalled venv the problem not gone